Windows context menu is jumping because of incorrect lazy loading
It is just a visual thing, but it still irritates me more and more. When I right click a folder or file, the context menu adds 3 loading placeholders - after about half a second, these are replaced by 1 (!) entry which causes the menu to jump.
Can this be fixed?
For better understanding, I added screenshots of the slow-motion video I took with my phone in the order they appear:




